# Optional route php patterns

Tags: php, routes

This is my code:

```
$url = '/'; //or
$url = '/slug'; //or
$url = '/slug/slug1'; //or
$url = '/slug/slug1/slug2'; //or
$url = '/slug/slug1/slug2/slug3';
$patterns = ???
preg_match_all($pattern, $url, $parts, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

What is the pattern to satisfy all the url above? Somebody can help me?

Comment: I'm not sure I quiet follow you, you do realize that your `$url` will always be `$url = '/slug/slug1/slug2/slug3';`  ?

Answer (score 1):

This pattern satisfy them all:

```
$pattern = "!^/(slug|slug(/slug\d+)+)?$!";
```

But of course, your question should be "Satisfy all the url above and no other", because "/" also matches them all...

Answer (score 0):

Why use a pattern?  If all you want is the parts of the url, a much simpler solution is ...

```
$parts = explode('/', trim($url, ' /'));
```

(Note that I `trim` leading and trailing spaces and `/` (forward slash) so that I don't get an empty string `""` as the first or last element of the $parts array--unless $url was just "/".)